# Mail issues in displaying £

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook-2010

I am creating a mail template in html for outlook which has symbol '£'
Ultimately when I see this through outlook mail it appears has Â£ . Can any body help me in fixing this?

Comment: If you feed the html as text, did you use the character escape (`&pound;`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing the text as UTF-8 but have not indicated the character set in the markup, or have indicated Windows-1252. The £ character is Unicode U+00A3. Encoded as UTF-8, this is the byte sequence 0xC2 0xA3. If that byte sequence is interpreted as Windows-1252, it becomes the two character sequence Â£.

You could try adding

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

to the `<head>` element of your email. I suggest that rather than the shorter `<meta charset="utf-8">` since Outlook uses Microsoft Word's HTML renderer rather than IE, and I'm not sure that that supports HTML 5.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set [HTML encoding](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/the_importance_of_content-type_character_encoding_in_html_emails) to use certain symbols. If you're sending from a C# program, then you can use [`MailMessage.BodyEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.